# compare two equivalence classes (cont.)

Tags: graph, ocaml

```
val compare : bool array array -> 'a list -> 'a list -> int
```

compare m generates the lexicographical order on list. I don't know how to fill `???`

```
let rec compare m c c' =
  match c with
    | [] -> (match c' with
            | [] -> 0
            | _ :: _ -> -1)
    | hd1 :: tl1 -> (match c' with
                    | [] -> 1
                    | hd2 :: tl2 -> ???
```

This is a function that I was trying to do by in a list of ints. but this function was not satisfy, it still missing to check in the rest of a list.

```
let cmp_classes m c c' =
   match c, c' with
    | i :: _, j :: _ ->
      begin
        match m.(i).(j), m.(j).(i) with
      (* same class: there is a path between i and j, and between j and i *)
          | true, true -> 0
      (* there is a path between i and j *)
          | true, false -> 1
      (* there is a path between j and i *)
          | false, true -> -1
      (* i and j are not compareable *)
          | false, false -> 0
      end
    | _ -> assert false
```

Could you please help me? Because when I tried with this function in int

```
let cmp_classes m i j =
   match m.(i).(j), m.(j).(i) with
      (* same class: there is a path between i and j, and between j and i *)
          | true, true -> 0
      (* there is a path between i and j *)
          | true, false -> 1
      (* there is a path between j and i *)
          | false, true -> -1
      (* i and j are not compareable *)
          | false, false -> 0
```

it still not return the right order in data I test.
I have been doing this function many times, it is really stuck when I have to try again and again but not find out what is wrong. Please I need your help. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

```
(* i and j are not compareable *)
      | false, false -> 0
```

This is completely wrong if you are trying to make a topologic sort of your elements. You are saying that incomparable elements are equals which is complete nonsense and WILL confuse the sort algorithm.

If you want to have a real topological order you should follow these steps:

- build an input list as the list containing only one representant per class; the output list is empty
- until the input list is empty:

  - pick a random root (with no input edge) in the input list and remove it from the list
  - append (in any order) all elements the root representants in the output list
- return the output list

Depending on the data-structures you are using, this algorithm can be more or less efficient, but your question is not enough precise for me to tell you more.